# How do I find the max value of an object and then return that values property in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to take the property with the max value and return the property? From an object in an object, how can this be done in JS? or is there something in jQuery that would make it easy?

So for example for "president", I need to return "Louise"

```
voteCount
{ 
    president: 
    { 
        Bob: 3,
        Mary: 1,
        Cindy: 1,
        Louise: 10,
        Fred: 4,
        Ivy: 1,
        Nate: 1,
        Oscar: 1,
        Paulina: 1,
        Tracy: 1,
        Wesley: 1,
        Steve: 1 
    },
    vicePresident: 
    { 
        Devin: 1,
        Hermann: 11,
        John: 1,
        Alex: 3,
        Kerry: 2,
        Mary: 1,
        Oscar: 1,
        Nate: 1,
        Bob: 2,
        Steve: 1,
        Yvonne: 1,
        Zane: 1 
    },
    secretary: 
    { 
        Gail: 1,
        Fred: 14,
        Bob: 2,
        Ivy: 3,
        Mary: 1,
        Nate: 1,
        Devin: 1,
        Oscar: 1,
        Alex: 1,
        Valorie: 1 
    },
    treasurer: 
    { 
        Kerry: 2,
        Ivy: 14,
        Bob: 4,
        Fred: 1,
        Gail: 1,
        Tracy: 1,
        Xavier: 1,
        Hermann: 1,
        Mary: 1 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Hey, very new to all of this, so not sure what you mean?

Comment: @ste-fu: That's not json and an array doesn't make sense if what you need is key/value pairs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could get the keys and reduce based on the values

```
var key = Object.keys(voteCount.president).reduce(function(a, b) {
    return voteCount.president[a] > voteCount.president[b] ? a : b;
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/d02q0htd/)

̿'̿'̿\̵͇̿̿\з=(•̪●)=ε/̵͇̿̿/'̿'̿ ̿

`Object.keys` gets all the keys, as in Bob, Mary, Cindy etc. in an array.
Then `Array.reduce` reduces that array until only one value is left, and because it uses a condition like this

```
obj[key1] > obj[key2] ? key1 : key2;
```

it basically says if the value of Bob is greater than the value of Mary, return Bob, and on the next iteration test the value of Bob against Cindy and return whichever is greater, more readable like this

```
if ( obj['Bob'] > obj[Mary] ) {
    return 'Bob'; 
} else {
    return 'Mary'; 
}
```

and it does that until only the name with the greatest value remains.

Comment: @adeneo Excellent code. I was working on an answer that was much longer and involved multiple in loops. Could you add more of an explanation to this?

Comment: Really appreciate your help. That does exactly what I want and get what it is doing :) can't do a vote up yet as too new to stackoverflow